# Is there a better way to return 0 if row doesn't exist?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

So my goal here is to select the id of John and return it to the calling application. If John doesn't exist, I want to return 0 to the application. What is the right way to do this?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ID From Table WHERE Name = 'John' ) 

    SELECT ID From Table WHERE Name = 'John' 

ELSE 

    SELECT 0
```

Comment: it's fine you can use also`IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 From Table WHERE Name = 'John' ) `

Comment: So you want 0 to be a magic value that represents no rows? Why can't the application just understand that no rows = no rows?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: There are valid reasons to do this, like in my case the easiest way to integrate a table using an existing API is by having an isActive column. The table in question does not have that field - if a record does not exist, it is not active. By creating a view from that table I avoid changing an existing application which in that particular case is not desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there's just one ID from John:

```
declare @ID int = 0
select @ID = ID From Table WHERE Name = 'John'
select @ID
```

Comment: Just note that if `Name` is not unique, this will pick an unpredictably arbitrary row, so you may not always see the same ID come out, even if no data changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Sql server, you can use :

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT ID From Table WHERE Name = 'John' ), 0)
```

For Oracle, the equivalent method is NVL(field,default_value);  (not tested)

Comment: Note that this will generate the following error if more than one row is found for `John`: `Msg 512, Level 16, State 1 / Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Comment: You are right. This mostly works for retrieving a particular id. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work even if `Table`has several rows `Name = 'John'`

```
SELECT ISNULL([Table].ID, ZeroID.ID) ID
FROM (SELECT 0 ID) ZeroID
    LEFT JOIN [Table] ON [Table].Name = 'John'
```